# how to see the data in DataLoader in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I see something like the following in the examples on Github.
How can I see the type of this data (shape and the other properties)?

```
train_data = MyDataset(int(1e3), length=50)
train_iterator = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=1000, shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inspect the data with following statements:

```
data = train_iterator.dataset.data 
shape = train_iterator.dataset.data.shape  
datatype = train_iterator.dataset.data.dtype
```

You can iterate the data and feed to a network as:

```
for nth_batch, (batch,_) in enumerate(train_iterator):
    feedable = Variable(batch)
    #here goes neural nets part
```

As Ivan stated in comments Variable is deprecated (although it still works fine) and Tensor itself now supports autograd, so the batch can be used in neural net.

```
for nth_batch, (batch,_) in enumerate(train_iterator):
    #feedforward the batch
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Variable`, it has been deprecated, [see here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated).